# Can a Mondrian Cube be Browsed By Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, ssas, data-warehouse, olap, mondrian

Is it possible to browse a Mondrian Cube through Microsoft Excel? like it is done with Microsoft SSAS? If not is there a possibility to use Sharepoint as a front end to browse a Mondrian cube?

Answer (score 5):

[Simba](http://www.simba.com) provided an ODBC driver to connect to mondrian XMLA service for Microsoft excel.

You can also try another pure javascript pivot table solution which mimics all functionality exactly like microsoft excel at [webpivottable.com](http://webpivottable.com)  . It's a client side solution and connect to any kinds of XMLA service directly. No any driver and plugin needed, no back end dependence. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlaconnect/

This allows you to use pivot tables directly on Mondrian

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of sharepoint reading directly from a mondrian cube, I dont know how that would work.

There are plugins for excel from a company called "Simba" that do allow you to read directly from a mondrian cube.  I've not personally used it, but I know of people that have in the long distant past.

If you're looking for a nice interface and are only a community user, have you looked at Saiku?  Obviously it's server based, but the UI is so simple to use, any end user should be able to get to grips with it..

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise editions of Jaspersoft have an Excel plugin for Mondrian

Answer (score 1):

I've also used this open source connector http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlaconnect and I am very satisfied with it:. These guys also said that it works in Sharepoint. You can read more about it here: http://www.arquery.com/Sharepoint%202013%20and%20Arquery.pdf